# how do we know if what customer says meet the intent?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm new to Dialogflow and I want to learn something from it. Currently I'm stuck with 2 problems. First is how do we know if what customer says meet the intent?:
According to google's tutorial, it puts in training phrases:like the screen shot. [In my case, I don't know how to trigger the intent. I tried My favorite color is Tony. It would ask as what I expected:What's your favorite color. But if I just say, Tony, It would goes to the fallback case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Iwy.png) I'm confused about how would the intent be trigger. Is it by entity? or something else?

In addition, I currently wrote a coupon lines of code on linux(which could convert to other language as well) to turn on and off a board's led light(my friend helped me). However, since I'm new to dialogflow and I want to do things like: If I talk to google, it would turn it on/off. I'm wondering how should I do it. Could I get some hint? I never learned api before and I could certainly learn it on my own. I just wanna need some help. 
p.s: I learned one year C++, so I'm not familiar with javascript, if completing this project requires javascript, I would certainly do that. Just need some hint pls. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that you need not learn any other language if you are already good at something & that is cause Dialogflow offers you SDKs for that. You can check it out over here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks. 
Now coming to your query, when user enters anything, that query comes to dialogflow & then it tries to find matches between different training phrases that you have entered in your intent. If there's a match found, having scored more than threshold, it sends us the response defined for that intent. You can even define custom entities, such as for colors, it would just help dialogflow to find more accurate intent. Following snaps should help you understand a situation better:
1. Intent-1
[image]
2. Intent-2
[image]
3. Custom entity
[image]
4. Output
[image]

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: I got you, Thanks a lot!but my problem is there is a 'prompt' section for actions and parameters I think that for the agent to ask a certain question if parameters are not met. Under that circumstances, how would that prompt be invoked?Is it by the number of entities matched? or is the threshold which I can check or adjust for my own agent?

Comment: Threshold has nothing to do with entities. If you have two entities suppose date & email, if any one of that is missing in user query, prompt will be involved.

Comment: Thanks. But in my example, if I only type a word like:rude. it would not trigger the intent, but if I say my favorite color is rude, it would trigger the intent and prompt. Why? my training phrase has both pink and my favorite coloir is black, why the previous one is not triggering?